# How to add parameter to delete link?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters, link-to

I have a standard delete link, and want to add a parameter to it:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", item, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete, :foo => 1 %>
```

The parameter shows up in the html a tag, but does not make to the server. I get "undefined local variable or method `foo'".

Here is how I am accessing it in the controller:

```
def destroy
    puts "params[:foo]:" + params[:foo].to_s 
    .
    .
    .
    redirect_to edit_bar_path(params[:foo])
```

The output is params[:foo]:

Comment: How are you trying to access that variable on the server side?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<%= link_to "Delete", item_path(:id => item.id, :foo => 1), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: for rails 5, the :confirm needs to put inside data key.
```link_to "Destroy", item_path(id: item.id, foo: 1), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, method: :delete```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for:

```
item_path(item, :foo => 1)
```

It should appear in your params